# How to use Chunker Class in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, opennlp, part-of-speech

The `ChunkerME` class in OpenNLP has a `chunk()` method which takes two `String[]`. The first one should be the tags (tags from part of speech tagging process) and the second one is the actual terms.

I'm having a tagged string in the format of `Sir_NNP Arthur_NNP Conan_NNP...` and I'd like to chunk it using the ChunkerME class. However the chunker does not accept this string as is. however the OpenNLP command line has a command (opennlp ChunkerME en-chunker.bin) which directly accepts a tagged sentence and return a chunked sentence.

How can I use something like the one in the command line.